# Exim rewrites from to default user

Tags: php, exim

I am running a Centos 6.4 server with Directadmin and Exim installed. We are using outgoing filtering together with Spamexperts.com. Somehow when I send email with PHP the envelop sender is being rewritten to the default Directadmin user. I cannot find out why.

The PHP script:

```
<?php
$to  = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: info@testdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@testdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-finfo@testodmain.com");
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

When executing the above PHP code Exim will log the following:

```
2014-03-19 10:32:29 1WQCrN-000511-4Z <= userX@testdomain.com U=userX P=local S=446 T="the subject" from <userX@testdomain.com> for me@mydomain.com
2014-03-19 10:32:29 1WQCrN-000511-4Z ** me@mydomain.com F=<userX@testdomain.com> R=spamexperts_smarthost_router T=spamexperts_smarthost_transport: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<userX@testdomain.com> SIZE=1483: host smtp.antispamcloud.com [46.165.209.5]: 550-Verification failed for <userX@testdomain.com>\n550-Previous (cached) callout verification failure\n550 Invalid sender <userX@testdomain.com>
2014-03-19 10:32:29 1WQCrN-000516-I1 <= <> R=1WQCrN-000511-4Z U=mail P=local S=1544 T="Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" from <> for userX@testdomain.com
2014-03-19 10:32:29 1WQCrN-000511-4Z Completed
2014-03-19 10:32:32 1WQCrN-000516-I1 => userX@testdomain.com F=<> R=spamexperts_smarthost_router T=spamexperts_smarthost_transport S=1586 H=smtp.antispamcloud.com [46.165.209.5] X=TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 C="250 OK id=1WQCrW-00033I-Lu"
2014-03-19 10:32:32 1WQCrN-000516-I1 Completed
```

The critical part is the part in bold:

2014-03-19 10:32:29 1WQCrN-000511-4Z <= userX@testdomain.com U=userX P=local S=446 T="the subject" **from < userX@testdomain.com>** for me@mydomain.com

When I change the PHP script to:

```
<?php
$to  = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: info@testdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@testdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-finfo@testodmain.com");
//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Exim log shows the following:

```
2014-03-19 10:48:09 1WQD6X-000569-IR <= info@testodmain.com U=userX P=local S=442 T="the subject" from <info@testodmain.com> for me@mydomain.com
2014-03-19 10:48:13 1WQD6X-000569-IR => me@mydomain.com F=<info@testodmain.com> R=spamexperts_smarthost_router T=spamexperts_smarthost_transport S=459 H=smtp.antispamcloud.com [198.7.58.154] X=TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 C="250 OK id=1WQD6P-0002nu-00"
2014-03-19 10:48:13 1WQD6X-000569-IR Completed
```

See that the critical part is not being rewritten:

2014-03-19 10:48:09 1WQD6X-000569-IR <= info@testodmain.com U=userX P=local S=442 T="the subject" **from < info@testodmain.com>** for me@mydomain.com

Additional information:

stripped exim.conf

```
[...]

syslog_duplication = false
local_from_check = false
local_sender_retain = false
untrusted_set_sender = *

[...]

# TRUSTED USERS
# OPTIONAL MODIFICATIONS:
# if you must add additional trusted users, do so here; continue the
# colon-delimited list

#trusted_users = mail:majordomo:apache:diradmin:${readfile{/etc/exim.users}}
trusted_users = mail:majordomo:apache:diradmin:userX:
trusted_groups = apache:userX

######################################################################
#                      REWRITE CONFIGURATION                         #
######################################################################

begin rewrite
 #* info@testdomain.com  F

# There are no rewriting specifications in this default configuration file.

######################################################################
#                      ROUTERS CONFIGURATION                         #
#            Specifies how remote addresses are handled              #
######################################################################
#                          ORDER DOES MATTER                         #
#  A remote address is passed to each in turn until it is accepted.  #
######################################################################

# Spamexperts
begin routers
 spamexperts_smarthost_router:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  ignore_target_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8
  condition = "${perl{check_limits}}"
  transport = spamexperts_smarthost_transport
  route_list = $domain smtp.antispamcloud.com::587
  no_more

# Remote addresses are those with a domain that does not match any item
# in the "local_domains" setting above.

# This router routes to remote hosts over SMTP using a DNS lookup. Any domain
# that resolves to an IP address on the loopback interface (127.0.0.0/8) is
# treated as if it had no DNS entry.

#lookuphost:
#  driver = dnslookup
#  domains = ! +local_domains
#  ignore_target_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8
#  condition = "${perl{check_limits}}"
#  transport = remote_smtp
#  no_more

[...]

# Spamexperts
begin transports
 spamexperts_smarthost_transport:
  driver = smtp
  hosts_require_tls = smtp.antispamcloud.com

# Spam Assassin
spamcheck:
  driver = pipe
  batch_max = 100
  command = /usr/sbin/exim -oMr spam-scanned -bS
  current_directory = "/tmp"
  group = mail
  home_directory = "/tmp"
  log_output
  message_prefix =
  message_suffix =
  return_fail_output
  no_return_path_add
  transport_filter = /usr/bin/spamc -u ${lookup{$domain}lsearch*{/etc/virtual/domainowners}{$value}}
  use_bsmtp
  user = mail
  # must use a privileged user to set $received_protocol on the way back in!

[...]
```

*Extra notes:

- local_from_check = false, local_sender_retain = false and untrusted_set_sender = * has no effect.
- userX is the Directadmin user/reseller
- When I enable the exim rewrite part the mail will be delivered, but ofcourse every mail will have a Return Path of < info@testdomain.com> which is not desirable.*

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's best IMHO not to use mail(), but instead add a good php mail class such as PHPMailer to your app.

Detailed answer:

There are two main parts you must manage when sending an email:

1. the message headers/body.
2. the smtp conversation between the mail servers which establishes the sender and recipient(s), often times referred to as envelope settings.

Your code is setting headers, which address things in item #1 only.  Your code's problem is that the "envelope sender", which is part of item #2 is not being explicitly set, so Exim is using the default which is $USER@$HOSTNAME.  Google for "**example SMTP conversation**" to understand why and **when** these things are important.

In general when using the php *mail()* command, it is difficult and non-obvious how to get the envelope settings to values you want.  Instead, use something which with more configurability that can make an actual SMTP connection, (instead of calling /usr/sbin/sendmail directly).  Yes, it's even better when the SMTP server is on localhost, the same principles apply.  When you can specify everything in the envelope for an actual SMTP connection, such as the [PHPMailer class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456761/611911), all of these issues you are fighting will go away.

It is also worth noting that the answer immediately below that shows how to use ini_set() to resolve the issue with the *mail()* command, but I still prefer using PHPMailer.